# SharedPreferences dentro de cada item do ListView

Tags: android, listview

Vamos logo ao exemplo:

Eu tenho dois itens na minha `ListView`:

```
Item 1

Item 2
```

Dentro de cada item tem uma calculadora que armazena o resultado.
Sendo que:

```
Item 1 = 0

Item 2 = 0
```

Na calculadora que fica no item 1, eu adiciono 20 ou qualquer outro número que eu queira adicionar, e então o item 1 vai armazenar o resultador para min, com o `SharedPreferences`.

Agora como eu quero que o `item 1` e o `item 2` estejam:

```
Item 1 = 20

Item 2 = 0
```

Mas na realidade eles ficam assim:

```
Item 1 = 20

Item 2 = 20
```

Resumindo: Eu adicionei apenas para o `Item 1` o valor `20`, o `Item 2` está com `20` também sendo que eu não adicionei nada ao `Item 2` apenas ao `Item 1`, eu queria que quando eu adicionasse o valor no `Item 1` ele guardasse, e os outros valores continuassem 0.

É isso espero que vocês possam entender.

Answer (score 2):

Gustavo,

você precisa salvar cada item com uma chave (key) diferente. Exemplo:

```
SharedPreferences  save = getSharedPreferences("save",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
editor.putFloat("valor1", valor1);
editor.putFloat("valor2", valor2);
editor.commit();
```

O que está acontecendo é que você está usando a mesma chave (key) para salvar os itens, isso faz substituir o último valor salvo.

Comment: Mais como eu vou criar uma key diferente sendo que eu não sei quatos items da lista o usuario vai criar ?

Comment: O sistema é o seguinte eu tenho aquela lista lá que é criada com o SQL, e dentro do clique do item da lista eu quero fazer isso mais não sei como fazer cada key diferente dentro do item.